# onchange js can't work in yii2 php select

Tags: javascript, yii2-advanced-app

when I select an option the code js doesn't work to appreat th input type number 
my Select Option :

```
<div class="gjf2">  
<div class="select" >
<?=$form->field($model, 'cat')->dropDownList($categoryFilters['cat']['options'],['class' => 'js-example-basic-single select-hidden'],['onchange'=>'myFunction()'],['id'=>'mySelect'],['options'=>['0' => ['disabled' => true],$select => ['selected' => true]]])->label(""); ?>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

my js code :

`function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<input type="number"/>';
}`

Comment: [Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable demo that reproduces the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: how can i do  Onchange js in Yii2 (php) Dropdownlist

Answer (score 1):

`DropDownList` should be :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'cat')->dropDownList(
     $categoryFilters['cat']['options'],
     [
         'class' => 'js-example-basic-single select-hidden',
         'onchange' => 'myFunction()',
         'id' => 'mySelect',
         'options' => ['0' => ['disabled' => true, 'selected' => true]],
 ])->label(false) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

put onchange in 2nd array which is an option array , means you need to do like this

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'cat')->dropDownList($categoryFilters['cat']['options'],['class' => 'js-example-basic-single select-hidden' ,'onchange'=>'myFunction()'])->label(""); ?>
```

please refer to this:
https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/723/creating-a-dependent-dropdown-from-scratch-in-yii2